# Native HTTP not working after adding /ngx library in IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework

earlier it was working after i created new project using "ionic start Sample blank --v2" native http is not working

Answer (score 0):

what is your `"@ionic-native/http"` version ? / you can check and change version from `package.json`

I'm using `"@ionic-native/http": "^4.10.0"` and its stable. You can try to downgrade this version.

don't forget `npm install` after the change in `package.json`